# Gorilla Websocket manual close client connect

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I try to close connect manual(use [Dark WebSocket Terminal](https://dwst.github.io/)),but the client tell me 1005 (No Status Rcvd)
Server:

```
ReadLoop:
for {
    mt, message, err := c.ReadMessage()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("read:", err)
        log.Println("messageType:", mt)
        if websocket.IsUnexpectedCloseError(err, websocket.CloseGoingAway, websocket.CloseAbnormalClosure) {
            log.Printf("error: %v", err)
        }
        c.WriteMessage(websocket.CloseMessage, websocket.FormatCloseMessage(websocket.CloseNormalClosure, ""))
        break ReadLoop
    }
    log.Printf("recv: %s", message)

    //do sth in here

    err = c.WriteMessage(mt, message)
    if err != nil {
        //WriteMessage wrong
        log.Println("write:", err)
        break ReadLoop
    }
}
```

It is not work and show the expected outputting the following:

```
read: websocket: close 1005 (no status)
messageType: -1
error: websocket: close 1005 (no status)
```

How should i go about this?

Answer (score 0):

The peer closed the connection without sending a status.  You can suppress logging of this status by adding `websocket.CloseNoStatusReceived` to the `websocket.IsUnexpectedCloseError` arguments.

```
    if websocket.IsUnexpectedCloseError(err, websocket.CloseGoingAway, websocket.CloseNoStatusReceived) {
        log.Printf("error: %v", err)
    }
```